# Sort list of strings by Year and Month

Tags: javascript

I have a list of strings

```
const mylist = ["October 2020","December 2022","November 2020" ,...etc]
```

I would like to sort by year and month.
How can I go about this without using external libraries/modules?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sorting?

```js
const mylist = ["October 2020", "December 2022", "November 2020"]
const sorted = [...mylist].sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
console.log(sorted)
```